# Geometric\Graphical verification of $ads=vdv$?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

In my Engineering Dynamics class, I've encountered this equation $ads=vdv$.  I could not wrap my head around why it was true, but I was able to come up with a verification of it as such:

$\mathrm{ds}=s'(t)\mathrm{dt}=v\mathrm{dt}$ and $dv=v'(t)\mathrm{dt}=a\mathrm{dt}$.  This yields $a*v\mathrm{dt}=v*a\mathrm{dt}$, "proof" (such as it is) complete.  However, I still have some issues.  I assume if I have $a(b\mathrm{dt})$, it is equal to $b(a\mathrm{dt})$ because either they are constants or to be evaluated $t$ must be taken consistently, but I can't prove it formally.

Also, I can't really *see* intuitively why this is true.  I can see why $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is the derivative, and graphically so.  Simply draw the graph where we take a value of $f'(x)$ and multiply it by $\Delta x$ to get $\Delta y$ (of course, $dy$ only equals an arbitrarily chosen $\Delta y$ if $f(x)$ is linear.)  But I can't even figure out how to derive the first relationship.

So I suppose the meat of my question is if someone would be so kind as to give a better (preferably graphical) description of why $ads=vdv$?

Answer (score 1):

i would say (if i understand correctly) your derived proof $a*v\mathrm{dt}=v*a\mathrm{dt}$ gives the desired understanding.

The relation is about **areas** (if seen geometricaly), the *area of the traversed space (times) the acceleration of traversal is equal to the area of velocity increase (times) velocity of traversal*, symbolicaly:

$$ads=vdv$$

Why? Because acceleration is velocity increase and space traversed is (infinitesimaly) equal to velocity.

As a sidenote, Calculus (differential and integral), as used by Newton and Leibniz, actually stems from geometry and geometric considerations. The analytic treatment is a later development. They were able to produce valid and important results without analytic methods, exactly because they relied on geometry (see for example [differential triangle by Barrow](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/The_rise_of_calculus.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Before we can go into proving the formula $a\,ds=v\,dv$ we need a clear idea of what $ds$, $dv$, and $dt$ are. On a heuristic level they are "infinitesimal quantities" that are tied together in understandable ways. E.g., $ds=v\,dt$ is saying that the small increment of $s$ during the small time interval $dt$ is equal to the momentaneous velocity $v$ times $dt$. But note that the word "momentaneous" used here indicates that there is an additional variable lurking behind, namely $t$, which is not appearing in the formula $ds=v\,dt$.

For an arbitrary function $t\mapsto u(t)$ and a given point $t$ in time we have, by the definition of derivative,
$$u(t+T)-u(t)=u'(t)\, T \ +o\bigl(|T|\bigr)\qquad(T\to0)\ .$$
In the "modern" view of derivative this is expressed in "differential form" as
$$du(t):\quad  T\mapsto u'(t)\,T\tag{1}$$
whereby now the derivative of $u$ at time $t$ appears as a linear functional on the increment vectors $T$, small or large. For the "special" function $\bar t: \>t\mapsto t$ we of course have
$$\bar t(t+T)-\bar t(t)\equiv T\ ,$$
so that, trivially,  $$d\bar t(t): \quad T\mapsto T\ .$$
If we compare this with $(1)$ we can say that the functional $du(t)$ is a constant multiple of the functional $d\bar t(t)$, whereby the proportionality factor is $u'(t)$:
$$du(t)= u'(t)\>d\bar t(t)\ .$$
If we omit some $(t)$ and the bar over the $t$ in $(2)$ we arrive at the formula $du=u'(t)\>dt$,  which we are fond of since calculus 101.

After all this abstract nonsense the proof of the formula $a\,ds=v\,dv$ is as simple as you proposed: We have a base function $t\mapsto s(t)$, then the "derived" functions $v(t):=s'(t)$, and $a(t):=v'(t)$. Apply the principles explained here, and obtain
$$a(t) ds(t)= a(t) s'(t) dt =v(t)\>v'(t) dt= v(t)\>dv(t)\ .$$
This is not an equation about obscure infinitesimal quantities, but about linear functionals defined on the one-dimensional tangent space at $t\in{\mathbb R}$.